# Sending Email Reminders on Monthly and quaterly basis

Tags: visual-workflow, scheduled-apex, time-dependent-workflow

I have a requirement where I have to send out  email reminders on quarterly basic i.e.. twice.

Once mid first month of quarter and on the end of 2nd month of quarter based on a condition (condition on Role of contact) on contact object.

Currently, The flow to schedule email alerts is  restricted to daily and weekly. Can you please suggest a workaround in details for the above criteria?

Answer (score 1):

So, use a Scheduled Flow that runs daily

- In the first condition block, determine if the current date is a valid mid quarter date
- If NO, do nothing
- If YES, then use Flow Action elements to send emails

Answer (score 0):

Please create a new workflow rule. In criteria condition you need to check it's meet your condition as,

- Condition on role of Contact
  AND
- date (mid of first month quarter/ end of second month quarter)

Then after you can create an e-mail alert action to send email to the required members.

Please let me know if it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd advise against workflow rules as SFDC has deprecated these; automation should be done with Flow